# A Smart Group of Contacts

Tags: contacts, smartgroups

We made around 100 contacts at a recent conference. How can I set up a smart group of these contacts that are not currently in our database?

Answer (score 3):

I would assign a tag to the contact when you import them, then do a search for that tag and create the smart group from the search results.

Comment: If your organization uses the Source field for contacts, this would be an ideal time to use that field for entry/import, then search for that and create the smart group like Barbara said.

Comment: One thought to consider: if this group will not change (e.g., contacts won't be moving in and out of it, but rather the list of contacts will remain static), perhaps a smart group is not necessary.  You could add the contacts to a regular group at the same time that you import them.